# read txt file and add each column to different array in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, swing

My txt file is look like :

```html
1,2,6,8,10,3
0,3,5,0
0,1
1,6,90,6,7
```

I am reading txt file . but I want to create array for each column. 
[image]

for example :

array0 will contain : 1,2,6,8,10,3

array1 will contain : 0,3,5,0

how I can do that?

my code :

```
File file = new File("src/maze.txt");
 try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        // Read the maze from the input file

        ArrayList column1array = new ArrayList (); 
        ArrayList column2array = new ArrayList (); 
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            char c = (char) content;

            column1array.add(c);

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BufferedReader`, read each line of file, `split` it and convert it into `integer` array.

Also, you can declare a list of `integer` arrays and add the values into it as you process new lines. Below is an example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("src/maze.txt");
    List<Integer[]> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        // Read the maze from the input file
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            Integer[] array = Arrays.stream(tokens)
                    .map(t -> Integer.parseInt(t))
                    .toArray(Integer[]::new);
            columns.add(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean row and not columns.

If the number of rows is dynamic, you should read the file line after line with the `readline()` method of `BufferedReader`.

For each read line you should split it with the `,` character to store each numeric value. 
You could store token of a row in a specific List.

And you could store all the lists in a list.

I refer to a `java.util.List` as in your example you use a List and the number of elements by rows seems changing. So a List seems preferable.

```
    List<List<Integer>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    try (BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        String line = null;
        while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null) {
            ArrayList<Integer> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
            listOfList.add(currentList);
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            for (String value : values) {
                currentList.add(Integer.valueOf(value));
            }
        }

    }
```